# How can I get the data from the json one by one by using javascript/jquery on click event?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have the working code which fetches all the records from the json, but how can I make the records available one by one on the click of the button(next/previous)?

The following code is working to fetch all the records:

```
    div
    {
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px;
    }

    #msg {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .members {
        width: 500px ;
        background-color: beige;
    }
```

```
<input type="button" name="next" id="next"><br/>
<input type="button" name="previous" id="previous"><br/>


<div id="msg">
<table id="userdata" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Picture</th> 
        <th>audio</th> 
        <th>video</th> 
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url="json.php";
        $("#userdata tbody").html("");
        $.getJSON(url,function(data){
            $.each(data.members, function(i,user){
                var tblRow =
                    "<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+user.email+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.sex+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.location+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+"<img src="+user.image+">"+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+"<audio src="+user.video+" controls>"+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+"<video src="+user.video+" controls>"+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>" ;
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Grabbing the entire JSON response and then iterating through it with a loop is your best solution. Put your `$.each` loop outside the AJAX call and use your prev/next there.

Comment: @DevlshOne can you show with sample code

Comment: Can you show me what the returned JSON looks like?

Comment: @DevlshOne returned JSON : http://sco7.com/components/phonegap/json.php

Comment: @DevlshOne I tried to add search functionality to this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040471/jquery-not-fetching-results-from-json-based-on-search-input , But don't know why its not working, please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="NEXT" />
<br/>
<input type="button" name="previous" id="previous" value="PREV" />
<br/>
<div id="msg">
    <table id="userdata" border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>audio</th>
            <th>video</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var users = [];
var idx = 0;
var renderRow = function (idx) {
    var user = users[idx];
    var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + user.email + "</td>" + "<td>" + user.sex + "</td>" + "<td>" + user.location + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<img src=" + user.image + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<audio src=" + user.video + " controls>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<video src=" + user.video + " controls>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    $('#userdata tbody').html(tblRow);
};
var url = "json.php";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    users = data.members;
    renderRow(idx);
    $('#next').click(function() {
        idx++;
        if (idx > (users.length - 1)) idx = (users.length - 1);
        renderRow(idx);
    });
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        idx--;
        if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, well, better late than never.

Comment: I used your code, now i am wondering how to display records based on the search.

Comment: Based on what search? I don't think I understand what you're after.

Comment: I mean , I created the search input box and search button. On clicking the search button I need the data from the search input box to be matched with each json record and the records based on the matching criteria are to be displayed. Thanx in advance.

Comment: It's your code.. try something. You're basically asking me to write all of your code for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34761/discussion-between-baljeet-singh-and-devlshone)

Comment: @DevIshOne I did the search, but i found one problem with your code(this one). I think this part (if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
    if (idx > (users.length - 1)) idx = (users.length - 1);) not working, as when the user pressess the previous button and comes to the first record, and i tried pressing the previous button many time and then as many time i have to press the next button to get to the next record.

Comment: Ok.. those expressions should probably be moved into a more global scope of the code... let me make that edit.

Answer (score 2):

Below is something that will do 1 row at a time, i'm guessing you are wanting paging IE 25 rows at a time, but since that wasn't really clear in your question i didn't make that assumption.

I also highly recommend changing your code to implement [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

If you want the 25 rows per page you'd need to change `index` to `page` and then have a `page size` variable, and a `loop` in the function `ShowMembers`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="msg">
    <table id="userdata" border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>audio</th>
            <th>video</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Prev" onclick="ShowMembers(-1)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="ShowMembers(1)"/>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var members = [];
var index = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url="json.php";
    $("#userdata tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        members = data.members;
        ShowMembers(0);
    });
});

function ShowMembers(offset)
{
    index += offset;
     var tblRow = 
            "<tr>"
                +"<td>"+members[index].email+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+members[index].sex+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+members[index].location+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+"<img src="+members[index].image+">"+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+"<audio src="+members[index].video+" controls>"+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+"<video src="+members[index].video+" controls>"+"</td>"
                +"</tr>";

    if(index == members.length - 1)
        $("#btnNext").attr("disabled", true);
    else
        $("#btnNext").attr("disabled", false);

    if(index == 0)
        $("#btnPrev").attr("disabled", true);
    else
        $("#btnPrev").attr("disabled", false);

    $("#userdata tbody").html(tblRow);
}
```

Comment: @DevlshOne great minds... :) still weird to show just 1 row, hope this is what he wanted.

Comment: P.S. `$("#userdata tbody").innerHtml(tblRow);` should just be `.html()`, yes? And you seem to be missing some periods prior to the `attr` methods.

Comment: @DevlshOne Agreed! i missed all of the periods...also `html` is better than `innerHtml` because of IE7 and lower. Appreciate the help!