# jquery not fetching results from json based on search input?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have the working code which displays all the results from the json, I tweaked the code to display only the results based on the search, But i don't know what is the problem is, it still shows all the results,

The code is following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery PHP Json Response</title>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
}

#msg {
width: 500px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
.members {
width: 500px ;
background-color: beige;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="search-json-input" />
<input type="button" id="search-json-submit" value="search" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="NEXT" />
<br/>
<input type="button" name="previous" id="previous" value="PREV" />
<br/>
<div id="msg">
    <table id="userdata" border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>audio</th>
            <th>video</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var users = [];
var idx = 0; 

var url = "json.php";
    var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
    var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    users = data.members;

    renderRow(idx);
    $('#next').click(function() {
        idx++;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        idx--;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
});

$("#search-json-submit").click(function(){


    for(var y=0;y<users.length;y++){ 
    if((users[y].email).match(search_query_regex) ||
           (users[y].sex).match(search_query_regex) ||
   (users[y].location).match(search_query_regex)) {

        renderRow(y)

        }
     }
});

var renderRow = function (idx) {
    //alert(idx);
    if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
    if (idx > (users.length - 1)) idx = (users.length - 1);
    var user = users[idx];

    var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + user.email + "</td>" + "<td>" + user.sex + "</td>" + "<td>" + user.location + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<img src=" + user.image + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<audio src=" + user.video + " controls>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<video src=" + user.video + " controls>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    $('#userdata tbody').html(tblRow);


};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of json.php can be seen here: http://sco7.com/components/phonegap/json.php

Comment: Unfortunately in your [JSON input](http://sco7.com/components/phonegap/json.php) there is not a single `search_input` to be found. Could you provide an example *with* such strings too?

Comment: @cars10 I added the full html file, see now

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to fetch JSON into your event handler. Your code execute directly upon occurence, so it does not find any value on the input box.

```
$("#search-json-submit").click(function(){
    var url = "json.php";

    var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
    var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        users = data.members;

        renderRow(idx);
        $('#next').click(function() {
            idx++;
            renderRow(idx);
        });
        $('#previous').click(function() {
            idx--;
            renderRow(idx);
        });
    });

   //... Rest of the handler
});
```

Comment: I don't want to, because i want all the records to be displayed when the page opens (even before searching anything).